# Salesforce App - Lightning Component Border

Tags: lightning, page-layout, app

Is it possible to remove the grey borders and expand the layout of the component?
The component is displayed through a custom tab. This problem occurs only on the iOS app (Ipad).

[image]

This is how it appears in the browser:

[image]

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:isUrlAddressable">

<div>        
    <lightning:layout class="backgroundWhite">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="4">
            <div>                    
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="{!c.goToHome}" class="bold" target="_self">
                    TEST
                </a>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="4">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">                    
                <p>TEST</p>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>                  
    </lightning:layout>    

    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center headerFont">                    
                <lightning:formattedRichText value="TEST"/>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>

    <lightning:layout class="backgroundWhite slds-box slds-box_xx-small">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">                    
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="{!c.goToDCC}" class="bold">
                    TEST
                </a>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>

    <lightning:layout class="backgroundWhite slds-box slds-m-top_small" multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">  
                <p class="fontBlue bold">TEST</p>    
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">                               
            <lightning:input aura:id="passportNumber" name="passport" label="TEST" variant="label-stacked" autocomplete="none"/> 
        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">     
            <c:searchableInputComponent aura:id="searchableInput" label="TEST" values="{!v.country}"/>                    
        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12"> 
            <div class="slds-float_right">              
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="TEST" onclick="{!c.submit}"/>  
            </div>      
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</div>
```

Comment: So how about showing us the layout you used to create this?

Comment: I added the code